# Add missing left parentheses in Java

Tags: java, stack

I wanted to write a program that takes from standard input an expression without left parentheses and prints the equivalent infix expression with the parentheses inserted. For example, given the input

```
1 + 2 ) * 3 - 4 ) * 5 - 6 ) ) )
```

the program should print

```
( ( 1 + 2 ) * ( ( 3 - 4 ) * ( 5 - 6 ) ) )
```

My solution is not best optimized. So, I am looking for suggestions on how to improve/optimize it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;
 
public class ParenthesesCompleter {
 
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        
        Stack<Character> operators = new Stack<Character>();
        Stack<String> operands = new Stack<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
        {
            switch (line.charAt(i))
            {
                case '+':
                case '-':
                case '*':
                case '/':
                    // Operator case
                    operators.push(line.charAt(i));
                    break;
                case '0':
                case '1':
                case '2':
                case '3':
                case '4':
                case '5':
                case '6':
                case '7':
                case '8':
                case '9':
                    // "operand" case
                    String s = "";
                    s += line.charAt(i);
                    operands.push(s);
                    break;
                case ')':
                    // closing paren case
                    String a = operands.pop();
                    String b = operands.pop();
                    char c = operators.pop();
                    
                    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
                    buf.append("(");
                    buf.append(b);
                    buf.append(c);
                    buf.append(a);
                    buf.append(")");
                    
                    operands.push(buf.toString());
                    break;
                case ' ':
                    break;
            }
        }
        // case for no outer parentheses
        while (!operators.isEmpty()) {
            String a = operands.pop();
            String b = operands.pop();
            char c = operators.pop();
        
            StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
            buf.append(b);
            buf.append(c);
            buf.append(a);
        
            operands.push(buf.toString());
        }
        System.out.println(operands.pop());
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know that the right answer is not just adding opening parentheses to the beginning until the counts match?